# Data is not updated in Vue component when emit calls function

Tags: vue.js

**Note: when I upload small size image then the data refreshes and if the image is bigger like 1 mb then it doesn't refresh the data.**

I have a *add new product* modal and when I open it as below:

```
<NewProduct v-if="showNewProduct" @close-modal="showNewProductModal" @success="showSuccessAlert"/>
```

and when I add the product and the modal is closed by emitting as below:

```
Products.addProduct(form)        
.then(
this.$emit("closeModal"),
this.$emit("success"),
)
```

Then in the parent component the data is not refreshed and show the old data and if I refresh the page then it show the new data.

I get data as below in parent component:

```
data: function () {
    return {
    showNewProduct: false,
    productList: [],
    success: false,
    };
},

mounted() {
    this.getProductList();
},

methods:{
    showSuccessAlert() {
        this.getProductList(),
        this.success = !this.success,     
    },

    showNewProductModal() {
      this.showNewProduct = !this.showNewProduct;
    },

    getProductList() {
        User.getProductList()
        .then((response) => {
        this.productList = response.data;        
        });
    },
}
```

My goal is that when the modal is closed then the `productList` should be updated as well with the newly added data without page refresh.

**Add product API.**

```
  addProduct(form) {
    return Api().post("/addProduct", form);
  },
```

Comment: Seems you've missed "showNewProduct" method.

Comment: It was not necessary but I edited.

Comment: Still no information on how do you update your list with new record and how do you use them in the template. Probably there is some issue related to asynchronous processing. Try deleting one of emits and make all the logic inside one method.

Comment: The data is in ``productList`` and I call this function ``getProductList`` to get the data and after modal close I want to run ``getProductList`` but It doesn't load.

Comment: Also I noticed that if I upload small size image then the data is refreshed but if the image size is big then it will not refresh the data.

Comment: So it is something related to asynchronous processing. Make sure you start fetching record only after the upload is completed.

Comment: Can you add this your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is something related to asynchronous processing. Please, make sure you start fetching record only after the upload is completed.

```
Products.addProduct(form).then(() => { this.$emit("closeModal")} )


showNewProductModal() { this.getProductList()}
```

Comment: Can you write the code as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
Products.addProduct(form).then(({data: product}) => {
    //pass data to close model event
    this.$emit("closeModal", product),
    this.$emit("success"),
  }

showNewProductModal(product) {
      this.productList.push(product);
      this.showNewProduct = !this.showNewProduct;
    }
```

Comment: I added ``console.log('testing')`` inside ``showNewProduct`` function for testing and the log appear but the data is not updated.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot see the console log printed? Could you post the code for Products.addProduct(form) to give a better idea? Also, just to double confirm, once the closeModal event is emitted, you want to reload data, is that correct?

Comment: I mean that I can see the login console log but the data not refreshed it means that the watch is working but the data is not refreshed. Yes on closeModal I need to reload the data. Also, I added the ``addProduct``. 

Also, I noticed when I upload small size image then the data refreshes and if the image is bigger like 1 mb then it doesn't refresh the data.

Comment: Api().post("/addProduct", form); does this return the posted element?

Comment: yes it returns the data.

Comment: In that case you can simply return it together with the event and append that to your list, you don't really need to call the api again. I will update my answer.